# How do I pass QEvents to child widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, events

#### Here's the situation:

I have a custom widget subclassed from `QTabWidget` that I've implemented to accept `QDropEvents` for files.  When files are dropped on the `TabWidget` they are opened for editing.  This part works fine.  However, I want to implement drag and drop functionality as part of the editor (think like a LabView-esque GUI).  I have properly implemented the event handlers and `acceptsDrops` on the `EditorWidget` but the `TabWidget` receives all the events and attempts to process them as files.  I can differentiate file-related events from the editor's events by mimedata but I can't figure out how to pass the event from the `TabWidget`on to the appropriate `EditorWidget`.

#### So the question:

How can I pass a QDropEvent from the widget which received it from the system to another widget which it owns?  Alternatively, how do I tell the system which widget should receive the event, based on the contents of said event?

#### What I've tried:

I can't call the `dropEvent` method of the child as it's protected.  I could create a series of my own methods that pass the events around but that seems redundant and fragile.  I've looked into installing an EventFilter, but from what I can tell that only discards events, it doesn't say "not me try someone else."

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016069/how-to-prevent-member-qwidgets-or-qdialog-objects-taking-over-key-events-from-qm presents a similar problem where the solution involves redirecting events but it doesn't actually describe how to do that.

Comment: this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563862/how-to-pass-click-event-to-sibling-underneath-in-qt also presents a similar problem but the solution is to build custom methods or recreate a new system event while making yourself transparent and I have to believe there is a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving my own problem:
As Pliny stated the child should see the event first.  My problem appears to have been that in `EditorWidget` I had not implemented `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent` so even though I had implemented `dropEvent` in `EditorWidget` the `TabWidget` took control of the drag and therefore stole the drop.

Answer (score 3):

Intersting! I think that accepting the event in the parent widget, and then trying to forward it to the child widget, is not the right approach architecturally. It would basically violate encapsulation (objects handling their own events).

If I were you, I would investigate why the child widget isn't seeing the event first. Children widgets are on top of their parents, so your child widget should have a first go at the event. Did you call `setAcceptDrops(true)`?

When you fix that, in the child widget event handler you can analyze the event and call `event->ignore()` if the event should be forwarded to the parent QTabWidget. If you don't call `ignore()`, the child will "consume" the event and it will not be propagated to the parent!

Here's an old blog post on event propagation that could help:

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It wasn't quite `setAcceptDrops(true)` but there was a reason the child wasn't seeing the event first.  I've answered below.